# What is a good attack strategy for town hall 4?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have town hall level four in Clash of Clans. I have level 5 barracks with 70 spaces in my army camp. I am having trouble raiding. I have tried 40 goblins and six giants. I have also tried 35 Archers and 35 Barbarians. None have been very effective. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

5% Wallbreaker, 15% Giants(as meat shield),30% Archers and rest all are barbarians.I wouldn't use goblins unless their level 3+ so it is suggested no to use them.

As for raiding,send out Giants first(they have a lot of HP) then wallbreakers to have an open space for your barbarians to raid in,archers then take over destroying the resources.

Hope this will be of help :)
Clash On!

Comment: Definitely the best strategy. I have a level 6 town hall and still use this strategy.

Comment: Best army composition and plan of execution @Sparow

Answer (score 0):

Goblins are weak, I wouldn't use them until you get rid of defense, so use giants and archers, then send in goblins, or don't use goblins at all. I suggest giants and archers only.

Answer (score 0):

Concentrate on deployment. Combination of Barbarians and Archers is universally best.

If enemy has Mortars or Wizard Tower near deployment, spread your units. And, always put Barbarians in frontline and keep Archers behind. Barbarians have better HP, so the strategy works.

Answer (score 0):

For (Full) Collector Attacking/Town Hall Sniping:

35 Barbarians (35)
35 Archers (35)

For Base Destroying:

5 Wallbreakers (10)
8 Giants (40)
20 Archers (20)

Answer (score 0):

I use barbarians and archers. Use barbarians first but curve then around the base so splash damage doesn't destroy all troops. Then deploy archers behind barbarians.

Answer (score -1):

9 giants = 45 + 10 barbs = 55 + 15 archers = 70

Comment: While this might answer the question, it would be much more helpful if you went into a bit more detail about why this setup works over what the asker has already tried.

Comment: The asker wanted a strategy, meaning your plan of execution for this army composition as well.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade barracks and get balloons.  Kill air defense then send balloons.